# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4 in ajax call in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am binding data on dropdown index change event using ajax call using asp.net web form
following my Ajax code

```
var e = document.getElementById("<%=ddlEducation.ClientID%>");
                var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if (value == "0") {
                    $('#dvRecords').empty();
                    alert("Please Select Education");
                    return false;
                }

                var obj = { "iEduid": value};
                var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
                //Filling Grid View  
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'EditProfile.aspx/BINDEducationDATA',
                    data: myJSON,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (response) {
                        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lblstram").value = response.d[i].eduStream
                        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lbldescs").value = response.d[i].Edu_Description
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

when it it executing i am getting 1st error is parsererror next i am getting error saying  Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4.

above is my C# code

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<EduDesc> BINDEducationDATA(string iEduid)
    {
        List<EduDesc> details = new List<EduDesc>();
        DataTable dtManager = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Edu_Stream,Edu_Description from tbl_education WHERE ID='" + iEduid + "'", con);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dtManager);
        }

        foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtManager.Rows)
        {
            EduDesc logs = new EduDesc();
            logs.Edu_desc = (dtrow["Edu_Description"].ToString());
            logs.eduStream = dtrow["Edu_Stream"].ToString();
            details.Add(logs);
        }
        return details;
    }
```

any help will appreciated.

Comment: What does the JSON itself looks like? The error suggests it is incorrect.

Comment: {"iEduid":"35"}" this is my json generated

Comment: You need to create a model to collect your json data to web method like `class Sample { public string iEduid {get;set;}}` and then in web method you have to change the parameter to this model like `public static List<EduDesc> BINDEducationDATA(Sample model) {...}`

Comment: what will be correct way can you please help m=with it

Comment: This usually means there was an error and the web site returned html instead of json. Along with a 200 level status code since your error handler is not firing. Use your browser dev tools to trace the network and look at the response.

Comment: er-sho can you please post as ans

Comment: in response it return the HTML insted of JSON

Comment: So you are getting correct data but in xml format or is it an HTML 403/40x/500 or similar page? You might have to accept xml instead of json or change your service to send application/json.

Comment: i used application/json but still getting same response

Comment: Where did you use application/json? The client can ask for that, but the server may not be capable of responding that way so it will do what it can. Can you confirm my other question? Is is correct data as xml or is it HTML?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple areas of concern.

```
foreach (DataRow dtrow in dtManager.Rows)
{
    EduDesc logs = new EduDesc();

    // - extra parentheses.
    // - here you use logs.Edu_desc but in 'success' (below) you use Edu_Description.
    logs.Edu_desc = (dtrow["Edu_Description"].ToString()); 

    logs.eduStream = dtrow["Edu_Stream"].ToString();
    details.Add(logs);
}


success: function (response) {
    // here you're looking for [i], but what is i? you need an integer.
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lblstram").value =
        response.d[i].eduStream
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_lbldescs").value = 
        response.d[i].Edu_Description
},
```

In the success function, do a console.log(d) to double-check the results.
hth.